# Cant get the reactions to recognise on a specific message now

Tags: discord.js

In a pervious post I was having issues getting the bot to recognise reactions and the fix worked however and then changed it to react on a message that the bot says afterwards and now it isnt working again, I have tried changing the user condition so its the original command author but that didn't seem to work

So you run the code and it makes the embed perfectly and reacts to it however it doesnt recognise when you react and makes the timeout message

```js
exports.run = async (client, message, args) => { 
  
  message.delete()
  
  const MINUTES = 5;
  const questions = [
      { answer: null, field: 'placeholdquestion' },
      { answer: null, field: 'placeholdquestion' },
      { answer: null, field: 'placeholdquestion' },
    ]; //to add more questions just add another line of the above code {answes: null, field: `Question Here`}
    let current = 0;

const commanduser = message.author.id
  // ...

    // wait for the message to be sent and grab the returned message
    // so we can add the message collector
    const sent = await message.author.send(
      `${questions[current].field}`,
    );

    const filter = (response) => response.author.id === message.author.id;
    // send in the DM channel where the original question was sent
    const collector = sent.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, {
      max: questions.length,
      time: MINUTES * 60 * 1000,
    });

    // fires every time a message is collected
    collector.on('collect', (message) => {
//if (questions > 1 && questions < 10) {
      
      // add the answer and increase the current index HERE
      questions[current++].answer = message.content;
      const hasMoreQuestions = current < questions.length;  //change to be an imput of how many questions you want asked

      if (hasMoreQuestions) {
        message.author.send(
          `${questions[current].field}`,
        );
      }
    });

    // fires when either times out or when reached the limit
    collector.on('end', (collected, reason) => {
      if (reason === 'time') {
        return message.author.send(
          `I'm not saying you're slow but you only answered ${collected.size} questions out of ${questions.length} in ${MINUTES} minutes. I gave up.`,
        );
      }


      
      const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("LOA Request")
      
          .addFields(
                { name: 'placehold', value: questions[0].answer+'/10' },
                { name: 'placehold', value: questions[1].answer+'/10' },
                { name: 'placehold', value: questions[2].answer+'/10', inline: true },)
        .setColor(`#1773BA`)
        .setTimestamp()
        .setThumbnail("https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/772915309714735205/795378037813805126/mvg_clean_2.png")
        .setFooter("request by: " + message.author.tag);
        ;
            
  
message.channel.send(embed)
            .then(function (message) {
              message.react("")
              message.react("")})
      
const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    return ['', ''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === commanduser; //changed to try and fix it didnt work as message.author.id or this
};

message.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] } ) 
    .then(collected => {
        const reaction = collected.first();

        if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
            message.channel.send('you reacted with a thumbs up.');
        }
        else {
            message.reply('you reacted with a thumbs down.');
        }
    })
    .catch(collected => {
        console.log(`After a minute, only ${collected.size} out of 4 reacted.`);
     message.reply('you didn\'t react with neither a thumbs up, nor a thumbs down.');
    });
      
   
  });
 
  
      ;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a slight logic error. You need to fit the code from your second `filter` to the `message.awaitReactions` inside of your `message.channel.send(embed).then(function (message)...)` method. In your code, the bot is trying to check for reactions from the original `message`, which you already deleted (since the `awaitReactions` is outside the scope of your function where you send and react to the embed).

Like this:

```js
message.channel.send(embed)
    .then(function (message) {
        message.react("")
        message.react("")

        const filter2 = (reaction, user) => {
            return ['', ''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === commanduser;
        };

        message.awaitReactions(filter2, { max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] })
            .then(collected => {
                const reaction = collected.first();

                if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
                    message.channel.send('you reacted with a thumbs up.');
                }
                else {
                    message.reply('you reacted with a thumbs down.');
                }
            })
            .catch(collected => {
                console.log(`After a minute, only ${collected.size} out of 4 reacted.`);
                message.reply('you didn\'t react with neither a thumbs up, nor a thumbs down.');
            });
    })
```

Comment: Thats perfect thanks, sadly the way I was doing the filter doesnt work for what I was doing as I need anyone with a staff role to be able to react (this is so annoying to find how to do) but thanks for the help non the less :)

Comment: If I understood your issue correctly, then you can simply modify your second `filter` so that it checks if the `user` has a certain type of role.

Comment: The issue I am having is finding the way to check the `user` role of the user that reacted to the message, but will look into it thanks again